# How to find the output of a trained network for a random input in tensor flow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

So I am trying to write a NN that predicts whether an input number is positive or negative, so I modelled this and trained, also checked the accuracy of it. But I can not use this model, to explicitly check whether a number is positive or negative. I can only, check the accuracy, I can not use this for individual inputs like a function.

So this is my attempt;

This creates training data

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pickle
import bitstring
from collections import Counter

def binary(num):
    f1 = bitstring.BitArray(float=num, length=32)
    return f1.bin
def num2bin(num):
    return [int(x) for x in binary(num)[0:]]

pos=10*np.random.rand(1000)
pos_test=10*np.random.rand(1000)

neg=-10*np.random.rand(1000)
neg_test=-10*np.random.rand(1000)
```

This converts the training data to 32 bit form and labels it

```
def create_label_feature(pos,pos_test,ned,neg_test,test_size=0.1):
featuresp=[]
labelsp=[]
for x in pos:
    featuresp +=[num2bin(x)]
    labelsp +=[[1,0]]
featuresn=[]
labelsn=[]
for x in neg:
    featuresn +=[num2bin(x)]
    labelsn +=[[0,1]]
featurespt=[]
labelspt=[]
for x in pos_test:
    featurespt +=[num2bin(x)]
    labelspt +=[[1,0]]
featuresnt=[]
labelsnt=[]
for x in neg_test:
    featuresnt +=[num2bin(x)]
    labelsnt +=[[0,1]]
test_x=featuresp+featuresn
test_y=labelsp+labelsn
train_x=featurespt+featuresnt
train_y=labelspt+labelsnt

return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y

train_x ,train_y ,test_x, test_y=create_label_feature(pos,pos_test,neg,neg_test)
```

This trains the NN and then tries to determine whether -5 is positive or negative

```
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import pickle
import numpy as np



n_nodes_hl1 = 1500
n_nodes_hl2 = 1500
n_nodes_hl3 = 1500

n_classes = 2
batch_size = 100
hm_epochs = 10

x = tf.placeholder('float',shape=[None,32])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

hidden_1_layer = {'f_fum':n_nodes_hl1,
                  'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(train_x[0]), n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

# hidden_2_layer = {'f_fum':n_nodes_hl2,
#                   'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
#                   'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

# hidden_3_layer = {'f_fum':n_nodes_hl3,
#                   'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
#                   'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

output_layer = {'f_fum':None,
                'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_classes])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


# Nothing changes
def neural_network_model(data):

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

#     l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
#     l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

#     l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['bias'])
#     l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l1,output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['bias']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver() 
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i=0
            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+=batch_size
                
            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
       
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))
        a=num2bin(-5)        
        a=np.reshape(a,(1,32))
#       a=a[0,:]

#       print(sess.run(prediction, {x:np.array(num2bin(5))}))
        print(sess.run(prediction, {x:a}))

        
train_neural_network(x)
```

The last part of the code

```
    a=num2bin(-5)        
    a=np.reshape(a,(1,32))
    print(sess.run(prediction, {x:a}))
```

So I want to see wheter -5 is positive or negative, and I expected to have [0,1] as an output because that is how I labled negative numbers.

But instead I get

[[ -29.49657059  123.97122192]]

So what is the problem here?

## Edit

I add this following part to my code;

```
        for k in [-9,3, 5,-8,-77,-16,54.3]:
                a=num2bin(k)        
                a=np.reshape(a,(1,32))
                a=sess.run(prediction, {x:a}) 
                prediction_tensor = tf.sigmoid(a)      
                print(sess.run(prediction_tensor))
```

Then my output is

```
Accuracy: 0.999933
[[ 0.          0.85150468]]
[[  8.66709650e-01   8.56608536e-32]]
[[  7.24581242e-01   8.87260485e-37]]
[[ 0.          0.66523373]]
[[ 0.  1.]]
[[  0.00000000e+00   8.08775063e-16]]
[[ 1.  0.]]
```

So my code gives two component output, and if the first element is bigger than the second it means that the input is positive and if not it means that it is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't sigmoid your output, that's the unscaled value, and it looks normal. The loss function is applying the sigmoid function to those values before applying cross entropy. The values you see there are the unscaled values you feed to the loss function. If you look at the numbers without applying sigmoid then all negative numbers predict 0 and approach 0 as they go more negative, and all positive numbers predict 1 and approach 1 the more they go positive. This is of course exactly what the sigmoid function is doing for you. You've trained your network to output large negative or large positive numbers when it's confident about the result.

So, if you applied sigmoid to those values you'd get what you expected: ~[[0.00000001, 0.9999999999999999999]] or if you round, [[0,1]].

Incidentally, you don't need 2 outputs for the binary class case, you can just use one output, it's either positive or negative. The network will probably perform ever so slightly better with the one output than the two. Not that it's going to have a hard time predicting positive vs. negative numbers. :)

You can get the scaled (0,1) values by defining another tensor as such:

```
prediction_tensor = tf.sigmoid(a)
```

Comment: Please see my edit. The accuracy is, 0.999933,  but I still don't get [1 0] or [0 1] for every result for example I get [[  8.66709650e-01   8.56608536e-32]] for input 3. And I can tell this is positive since the first element is bigger. But is it supposed to be like this.  I mean can we tell this model is very good at determining the sign?

Comment: The first class is `0.87`, the second class is `0.0` (rounded to reasonable readable values). That looks very normal! Anything above 0.5 is rounded up to 1 (positive) and anything below 0.5 is rounded to 0 (negative). Again, you'd do better with 1 output since this is a binary classification, but with those results it's saying it's "pretty darn confident that the first element is true, and super duper confident that the second element is false". Note that if you trained longer it might manage to get more confident in value of the first element (e.g. it might get closer to 1)